# Does the Google Nexus 10 tablet-PC have a standalone GPS?

Tags: gps, samsung-nexus-10

Does the Google Nexus 10 tablet-PC have a standalone GPS, or does its GPS rely on GSM data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe Nexus 10 has GPS hardware which can provide location information without any aid from GSM or Wi-Fi sources - same as my Nexus 7 Wi-Fi only model.

I have used my Nexus 7 on road (without any data connection) and used is GPS capabilities.

I'm just wondering how a did you get this suspicion when the specification clearly says about availability of the GPS?

Answer (score 1):

The Nexus 10 has A-GPS, so it can speed up the time to the first fix, either via GSM (if it has one) or via network from an assistance server. See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assisted_GPS

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can turn off "Wi-Fi & mobile network location" from settings, which disables A-GPS features leaving you with plain, unassisted GPS.

You can read more from [Google Nexus 10 help: Manage location access](https://support.google.com/nexus/10/answer/2819558?p=settings_location&hl=en-GB&version=17&rd=1)

Answer (score 0):

The Nexus 10 has AGPS and also a hardware GPS built in.